# Specifying default Graph Style?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to see all my graphs as `GraphStyle->"DiagramBlue"` by default, what is the magic incantation to make this a reality?

Comment: `SetOptions[Graph, GraphStyle->"DiagramBlue"]`?

Comment: `PlotTheme` now works with `Graph` and has many nice styles, e.g. CoolColor. These affect not only the basic graph appearance, but also how HighlightGraph styles highlighted portions of the graph.